# Como eu pego os valores do campo?

Tags: javascript, mysql, ajax, json

Meu código

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 

  $('.formulario').submit(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); 
  
  var inputId = $('.inputId').val();
  
  $.ajax({ method: "GET" 
 ,url:"localhost/api/32327ed48666154acb54810521d6f01e0d5de59e/movi‌​es/…"
 , dataType: 'json', 
  }).done(function(json) { 
  
    console.log(json);
    $('body').append(
      'ID do Genero: ' + json.genre.id); 
    }); 
    
  });
});
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu estou tentando pegar os valores do campo **genre**, mas não estou conseguindo alguem poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Maycon, ao invés da imagem poste o código para que possamos ajudá-lo.

Comment: Bem-vindo Maycon Benito, ao perguntar sobre um problema no seu código, você conseguirá melhores respostas se der às pessoas código que elas possam usar para reproduzir o problema. Leia esse post https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas/5485#5485

Answer (score 0):

Seguinte, suponhamos que vc queira pegar o 'genero' dentro de 'genre'.
Para vc pegar valores de uma lista (ou json) dentro de outra lista, devemos usar um laço dentro de outro laço...
Exemplo. Supondo que seu JSON esta dentro de 'items':

```
for(var i = 0 ; i < items.length; i++){
    var currentGenre = items[i]['genre'];
    for(var f = 0; f < currentGenre.length; f++){
        //Aqui vc consegue pegar os valores que estão dentro de genre
    }
}
```

Apenas uma observação. Para isso funcionar, o que esta dentro de genre também tem que ser um objeto JSON e não uma string.... para transformar strings em json use o JSON.parse. um exemplo basico de seu uso.

```
var currentGenre = JSON.parse(items[i]['genre']);
```

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp 
Nesse link acima tem uma explicação de como ele funciona certinho

Answer (score 0):

Neste exemplo, temos uma string que pode ser convertida em um array JSON. Exemplo de parse:

```js
var myJson = 
{ 
   id: "1",
   genre: "[ {\"id\":\"81\", \"genero\": \"comédia\"} ]" 
};

var genre = JSON.parse( myJson.genre );

for(var i=0; i<genre.length; i++)
{
   document.getElementById('divGenero').innerHTML += genre[i].genero;
}
```

```html
<div id="divGenero"></div>
```